# Reset value before reach ceiling inside Loop

Tags: php, while-loop

i have a number of minutes as ceiling and tasks that demand time in minutes, im doing a while loop to sum the time required by the tasks until reach the ceiling, but im having a problem with one step in the loop, the first number is the loop, the second the task required time, the third is my ceiling. I must reset the the task_required_time variable before or once it reach the ceiling. Using

```
if ($task_required_time > $ceiling) {task_required_time = 0}
```

it reset after its over the ceiling:

```
1 - 120 - 2400
2 - 304 - 2400
3 - 424 - 2400
4 - 2092 - 2400
5 - 2212 - 2400
6 - 3580 - 2400 <---- here is when it reset as expected but should be in the step before.
7 - 120 - 2400
8 - 330 - 2400
9 - 450 - 2400
10 - 570 - 2400
```

I will appreciate some light on it.

Comment: Show us your existing code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're probably resetting it *after* rather than before

Comment: Do the for loop, count the length of your data then inside for loop make your if statement.

Comment: Hey Slick, is a simple loop:  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($duedates)) {

    if ($tiempo_para_mix > $tiempo_efectivo) {
        $tiempo_para_mix = 0;
    };

    $tiempo_para_mix += (($rows['tiempo_reproduccion'])*2)+($tiempo_tqc_final*60); 

    echo $x . "  - " . $tiempo_para_mix . " - " . $tiempo_efectivo . "</br>";


   $x++;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the compare at the begining of the code. this may help:

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($duedates)) { 
    if ($tiempo_para_mix + (($rows['tiempo_reproduccion'])*2)+($tiempo_tqc_final*60) > $tiempo_efectivo) { 
        $tiempo_para_mix = 0; 
    }; 
    $tiempo_para_mix += (($rows['tiempo_reproduccion'])*2)+($tiempo_tqc_final*60); 
    echo $x . " - " . $tiempo_para_mix . " - " . $tiempo_efectivo . "</br>"; 
    $x++; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i was stuck thats the way.